# Setup WLAN interface on Debian

Tags: debian, networking, wifi

I am trying to configure wlan on my dockstar. I installed `wireless-tools`, `zd1211-firmware` and `wpasupplicant`.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like this:

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid *myssid*
        wpa-psk *mypw*
```

My wlan0-interface is up and got an ip address.

However, I can only ping this address if the LAN interface is connected too. What am I missing?

Output of `route -n`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `route -n` (run as root or sudo)?

Comment: @Andrew I appended it to the original post.

Comment: I think that if the `eth0` interface is not configured at all, it should not be in the route. Could you post the output when `eth0` is not used? You can use `ifdown` to deactivate it.

Comment: @faif Okay, I'm now connected over `wlan0`. `route -n`:  `192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0`. Even if I unplug the cable, I can access my dockstar using both IPs?!

Answer (score 2):

In the provided routing table, there are two lines for the same network: one for `eth0`, one for `wlan0`.  This is not ideal.

Additionally, the default route for outbound traffic is via `eth0`.

What is probably happening is, when you unplug the Ethernet cable, the routing table lines for `eth0` remain, including the default route.  The host then tries to send all its traffic over that interface, despite the fact you have unplugged it.

You could adjust `auto eth0` to `allow-hotplug eth0` and install a separate piece of software to manage the device based on plug/unplug events.  Network-Manager works in this way and I believe has a CLI interface now.

Or, you could ensure that `eth0` had a netmask of `255.255.255.255`.  This would mean the machine would only use that interface for traffic directed at it, or in reply to such traffic, explicitly, and not as a default route.  Either reconfigure your dhcp server or configure `eth0` statically.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set that in the BIOS that if you put a cable in the RJ45 then the wifi will auto turn off, and if no cable connected, then the wifi turns on?

Comment: I've never seen a setting like this at the BIOS level. What BIOS have you seen with that feature?